# Is it possible to access MetaMask functionality for integration testing?

Tags: metamask, testing, ganache-cli

I'd like to be able to access MetaMask to test potential user actions.  I doubt it's possible to directly simulate sending transactions, but what I hope I can at least confirm is that transactions are being correctly fed to the plugin.  I've never had to test a plugin so I'm not sure if this is possible for any kind of plugin.

Since I should be able to trust MetaMask's ability to interact with networks, I can just mock the sending of the transaction with web3 so it's just confirming that transactions in MetaMask before they are submitted.

I'm planning to use Jest, Chromium, and Ganache.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: mock https://github.com/codingwithmanny/web3-react-jest-tests/blob/main/src/__tests__/App.test.tsx